# How to display an integer literally as a character

Tags: c++, char, int

I have an integer 1 and i want to display it as a character '1' in C++. So far I have only managed to convert it from say integer 65 to character 'A'.
How do you stop this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int theDigit = 1;
char ch = theDigit+'0';
```

This works because it's guaranteed<sup>1</sup> that the sequence of characters `'0'`...`'9'` is contiguous, so if you add your number to '0' you get the corresponding character. Obviously this works only for single digits (if `theDigit` is e.g. 20 you'll get an unrelated character), if you need to convert to a string a whole number you'll need [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (in C) or [string streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/) (in C++).

---

1. C++11, [lex.charset] ¶3:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

By the way, I suppose that they didn't mandate contiguity also in the alphabetical characters just because of EBCDIC.

Comment: This will also only work for single characters. A more universal solutions which also works with longer numbers would bei sprintf, or sprintf_s for the safe version.

Comment: @sehe, if you need to ask you're probably not using one of those encodings.

Comment: @sehe: I find it very odd that any character set doesn't have contiguous digits (even the idiotic EBCDIC got this right)... can you name any of those character sets you are referring to?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: oops you're right. That would be very rare. I somehow missed the logical fact that `'0'` doesn't hardcode the char-value for `'0'` :) Removing unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use the stringstream.

```
int blah = 356;
stringstream ss;
string text;

ss << blah;
ss >> text;
```

Now `text` contains `"356"`(without quotes). Make sure to include the header files and use the namespace if you are going to copy my code:

```
#include <sstream> //For stringstream
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i = 3;
char buffer [25];
itoa (i, buffer, 10);
printf ("Integer: %s\n",buffer);
```

Integer: 3

Comment: The question is tagged `c++` -- `itoa` is not in any C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

You did just ask about printing an integer, so the really simple c++ answer is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int value = 1;
  std::cout << value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to return 0 in `int main ()`

Comment: Yup. What I get for not compiling first. Could have been worse. I could have used `void main()`.

Comment: @Phoenica : Returning a value from `main` is completely optional, `0` is the default return value (§3.6.1/5).

Comment: @PhoenicaMacia: omitting `return 0` is okay. Quote from standard: `If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;`

Comment: Optional or not, I agree with @Phoenica. It's just the right thing to do.

Comment: @Misha: I don't like to clutter up my global namespace by doing a `using namespace std;` Better to call `std::cout`.

Comment: It would be "the right thing to do" if there were any semantic difference one way or the other, but in reality it's only a stylistic difference so there is no "right thing" -- it's purely subjective. Personally, I _never_ put that purely-redundant statement into my code.